# Why laravel passport api accept request without having headers?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel passport for API's. When I build api's I can post request to laravel through postman software and I figure out that laravel responding to API's without having headers.

I mean it does not matter that I am sending headers or no, API's always responding.

So is this right thing or I am missing something?

Can someone kindly guide me about it, I would like to appreciate.

Thank you so much

As per @codeForMoney comments I am adding my route script

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group([

    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function () {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

    Route::group([

        'middleware' => 'auth:api'

    ], function() {

        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

Comment: did you put `middleware('auth:api')` in your route?

Comment: @codeformoney can you please check I have added route script.